# removeEventListener() not removing function after added with addEventListener javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I've added a `mouseover` function with `addEventListener()` and am trying to remove it on `mouseout` with `removeEventListener()` . Adding the function works fine but it's not being removed on `mouseout`.

What is the problem with the code here ? How can it be amended to remove the function ?

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('a');

function highLight() {

var p = document.getElementById('p');
var strong = p.getElementsByTagName('strong');
for(var i = 0; i < strong.length; i++) {
     strong[i].style.color = 'red';
}   

}
elem.addEventListener('mouseover', highLight, false);

elem.removeEventListener('mouseout', highLight, false);
```

Comment: Do you know what `removeEventListener` does, and are you sure it's what you're looking for, as you have to remove the listener for the same event, not for some other event ?

Comment: Oh, and if you're trying to remove the color, you're way off!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the point is to remove the red color, and not really remove the eventListener

```
var elem = document.getElementById('a');

function highLight() {
    var p = document.getElementById('p');
    var strong = p.getElementsByTagName('strong');
    for (var i = 0; i < strong.length; i++) {
        strong[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
}

function unhighLight() {
    var p = document.getElementById('p');
    var strong = p.getElementsByTagName('strong');
    for (var i = 0; i < strong.length; i++) {
        strong[i].style.color = 'black';
    }
}


elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', highLight, false);

elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', unhighLight, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UBLRC/)

Comment: @moonshineOutlaw - So was the point to remove the red color? `removeEventListener`, as the name implies, removes the event listener so the event is no longer bound.

Comment: The right pattern is to remove the event listener, to avoid compounding listeners over time.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, I think you want add a 'mouseout' event below the 'mouseover' event, and then remove both in the callback function for 'mouseout'.

That is, something more like this:

```
elem.addEventListener('mouseover', highLight, false);
elem.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    elem.removeEventListener('mouseover');
    elem.removeEventListener('mouseout');
}, false);
```